# AGAIN Flutter List view Items do not appear

Tags: flutter, dart

Just copy the code below and run it you do not have to add libraries or anything else.
The problem is: custom paint items do not appear as listview.builder items, when I removed the listview.builder it appears.

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: ForTest(),
  ));
}

class ForTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: /*noteWidget() this will success*/ ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return noteWidget();
          },
          itemCount: 3,
        ));
  }
}

class NoteBoxCustomeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 375;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 812;
    path.lineTo(304 * _xScaling, 0 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(
      304 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
      22.92 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
      22.92 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      22.92 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
      0 * _xScaling,
      22.219 * _yScaling,
      0 * _xScaling,
      22.219 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      0 * _xScaling,
      22.219 * _yScaling,
      0 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
      0 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      0 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
      304 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
      304 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      304 * _xScaling,
      92.558 * _yScaling,
      304 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
      304 * _xScaling,
      0 * _yScaling,
    );
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

class NoteEdgeCustomeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 375;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 812;
    path.lineTo(22.946 * _xScaling, -3.087 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      -3.087 * _yScaling,
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
      0.023 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
      0.023 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
    );
    path.cubicTo(
      0.023 * _xScaling,
      19.559 * _yScaling,
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      -3.087 * _yScaling,
      22.946 * _xScaling,
      -3.087 * _yScaling,
    );
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}

@immutable
class ClipShadowPath extends StatelessWidget {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;
  final Widget child;

  ClipShadowPath({
    @required this.shadow,
    @required this.clipper,
    @required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      painter: _ClipShadowShadowPainter(
        clipper: this.clipper,
        shadow: this.shadow,
      ),
      child: ClipPath(child: child, clipper: this.clipper),
    );
  }
}

class _ClipShadowShadowPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Shadow shadow;
  final CustomClipper<Path> clipper;

  _ClipShadowShadowPainter({@required this.shadow, @required this.clipper});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = shadow.toPaint();
    var clipPath = clipper.getClip(size).shift(shadow.offset);
    canvas.drawPath(clipPath, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

Widget noteWidget() {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      ClipShadowPath(
        shadow: BoxShadow(
            color: Color(0x26000000), offset: Offset(0, 1), blurRadius: 3),
        clipper: NoteBoxCustomeClipper(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
      ClipShadowPath(
        shadow: BoxShadow(
            color: Color(0x26000000), offset: Offset(0, 1), blurRadius: 3),
        clipper: NoteEdgeCustomeClipper(),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

You can remove the listview.builder in scaffold's body and replace it with noteWidget() method to see the widget that I try to show it.

Answer (score 0):

They appear, but the problem is your Stack widget has an unconstrained height, so the first ListView item fills the whole screen. You need to constrain a list item to a max height in a listview. You can add a height constraint to your noteWidget, or you can use itemExtent property on the ListView.

Also, you should use the Flutter Widget Inspector tool, as you'd be able to see that the noteWidget's are in the widget tree.

Comment: I tried this before, but the problem is not because of the stack, I tried to put the custom paint without stack and it did not work too, but when I put height for the item, it appears in a weird way, so I think the problem is from custom paint with listview